# How to implement a Poisson Gamma model to predict study recruitment?

Tags: poisson-distribution, model, observational-study

After researching there are a lot of papers that suggest study recruitment can be modeled after a Poisson Gamma distribution. (which might just be a negative binomial distribution?) They also have a lot of the mathematical principles of how it works. The only problem is that I am not sure I am following it correctly.

This is what I have understood, so far. Please correct me if I am wrong.

The Poisson lambda is the rate of the recruitment times by the amount of time left in the study (assuming no site drops). In this case I was going to use the rate of the last 60 days by adding up all subjects and dividing by 60 for each site.

If I generate a random poisson distributed number for each site given their rate and than add them together I should get the total amount of subjects by the end of the study. If this is done 10000 times I can get the mean as the end point and than the .975 and .025 quartiles as an error. (which doesn't give a large range)

Of course recruitment rate varies throughout the study. To account for this people have used Gamma as the rate. Should the alpha (or shape) be 1 and the beta be the number of the previously calculated rate? This is were I am most uncertain and confused on how to pick the alpha and beta. From here I generated a 100000 random Gamma numbers and fed them into the poisson. (This is using rs rpois and rgamma)

It kinda looks like the papers, but I am completely unsure if this is a correct method. Also does it make sense that I am generating the models randomly like that and just taking the average? Is there an easier way? In addition would this model apply to screenings, screen fails, and randomizations?